# How to disable an option within a drop down?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm new and I need to solve a programming problem. I want to disable an option of a drop down field.

**Use Case:** People create a ticket, and they can control (with the dropdown) if they want to create it in a private way or within a group of other support employees. The private option should never be accessable, clickable or visible. Instead the only options should be options where they can chose the group they want to share this issue with (if there is only one group theyre member of, this one should be the standard ofc).

My problem now is, that the private option is some kind of the standard option and is the auto selected one. So i can't just use display: none to hide the private option because even if they can't see it, it's auto selected and when they click "Submit issue" it remains private. I need to delete this option in some way but my programming skills are not yet to be developed...

Another option would be -> if the "private request" option is selected the "Submit issue" button should be disabled.

Comment: Add `disabled` to the option. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled

Comment: To disable the "Submit issue" button you will have to add an event listener to the dropdown, when it changes to a specific option you disable the button, the same way @VladimirBogomolov suggests you do on the option.

Comment: The problem is I can only use CSS or javascrip to do this  and no html. What I can also do is "display: none;" but if I use that the whole dropdown will be hidden. -> a.js-dropdown-list {display: none;}
My problem here is, all the different choices are identified by a.js-dropdown-list or am I wrong?